# Why is Matcher.group() throwing illegal state exception?

Tags: java, regex

Why does the below code work fine

```
Matcher reg = Pattern.compile("(A|B)\\w{2}(C|D)").matcher("");
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (!loading || reg.reset(line).matches()) 
    {
        if (reg.reset(line).matches()) {
            String id = reg.group(1);
        }
    }
}
```

but

```
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (!loading || reg.reset(line).matches()) 
    {
            String id = reg.group(1);
    }
}
```

throws IllegalSyntaxException?

I was surprised because I am already calling matches in the if condition. The expectation is that it returns the string matching the group, throws the exception instead.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the error says it all:- _No match found_

Comment: Looks like `!loading` is true so `reg.reset(line).matches()` will not even be executed.

Comment: what is the value of `loading` ?

Comment: The boolean loading is false, but you are still trying to get the match via reg.group(1). In the first code sample you have an if-statement that is checking if there is a match, in the second code sample you removed that if-statement.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is easy to say why your code is not working, but proper solution would require knowledge about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user6188402 Incorrect. The pattern defines exactly how many groups will be available. The actual matching may leave many of them `null`, but they still exist. Besides, if the group didn't exist, you'd get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `loading == false`, `reg.reset(line).matches()` won't be executed, because `!loading` already is `true`. In your first example you then "again" check if there is a match and only then try to get the group. In your second example, you just assume that there is a match because you got there, which may not be true.

If the code you posted is all you do in this `if`-statement, you may get rid of the `!loading` check, as it doesn't matter if it's true or false - as soon as you find a match, you'll execute the code within the body, if you cannot find a match, it won't be executed.